# C# Async Foreach loop for huge volume of data

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have to process huge volume of data in a batch job

Program flow

```
var inputDataLst = contextObj.GetData(); //More that 10000 rows I will retrieve

foreach(var item in inpDataLst)
{
     //logic
}

Call context.SaveMethod(inpuDataLst);
```

I am trying to do something like

```
var tsklst = inputDataLst.Select(async pItem => 
{
   //Logic
});

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Compiler is giving warning and Resharper is suggesting me to make a sync method.

Can anyone suggest me how to handle this since I am going to have huge data I would like to do a Async operation..

Implementing @bruno suggestion

```
Parallel.ForEach(taskList, item => {
 item.StatusId = 2; //Completed
 LastUpdateUser = "Batch";
});
```

after loop completion I get taskList is NULL,

Comment: Is it really async you're after, or parallel? What is it you're doing in the logic? If it's not using shared state you could just use Linq's IEnumerable<T>.AsParallel() method, or you could uses the Parallel.For

Comment: I don't want to process that record one by one..

Comment: can you show the warning that the compiler is showing?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure he means parallel...

Comment: @oqx its all green line on the code..maybe resharper is giving that warning..

Comment: @RajGan you can hover over the underlined code and it'll tell you what is the problem, sometimes reharper and /or visual studio 15 will complain if you are trying to access a none-thread safe resource

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. It will handle your list asynchronously.

```
var inputDataLst = contextObj.GetData(); 


Parallel.For(0, inputDataLst.Length,
                index=> 
                {
                    //your logic, something like ProcessData(inputDataLst[index])
                });

context.SaveMethod(inpuDataLst);
```

You could also use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(inpuDataLst, item => { ProcessData(item) });
```

EDIT:

As per your edit additional comment, I wrote a very simple minimal working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO.RajGan
{
    class SomeData
    {
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateUser { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Last update user: {LastUpdateUser}; Status ID = {StatusId}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataList = new List<SomeData>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                dataList.Add(new SomeData() { StatusId = new Random(i).Next(1, 10), LastUpdateUser = $"User {i + 1}" });
            }

            Parallel.ForEach(dataList, item => 
            {
                item.LastUpdateUser = "Batch";
                item.StatusId = 2;
            });

            Debug.Assert(dataList != null);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it and it works, dataList is not null and all entries are accordingly updated. I cannot trace the reason why your list is null without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I tried to implement your solution and its returning null. all I will be doing in processdata() method is changing values in item's property. So I expect changes should reflect in inputDataList. But I am getting null. I have updated the code above..

Comment: yes its working for me. sorry I did a very silly mistake. contextObj.GetData();  was returning Ienumerable and I see it was not able to retain the vaule in parallel.Foreach. But when I return LIst<> then it works fine..